# How get properties for a inherits class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a `Person` class that inherits `EntityBase`:

```
public class Person : EntityBase
{        
   virtual public string FirstName { get; set; }
   virtual public string LastName { get; set; } 
   virtual public IList<Asset> Assets { get; set; }   

}
```

And

```
public class EntityBase : IEntity
{    
   public virtual long Id { get; protected set; }
   public virtual string Error { get; protected set; }
}
```

I need to get list of properties of self `Person` class:

```
var entity = preUpdateEvent.Entity;

foreach (var item in entity.GetType().GetProperties()) //only FirstName & LastName
{
   if (item.PropertyType == typeof(String))               
      item.SetValue(entity, "XXXXX" ,null);
}
```

Now `GetProperties()` is include : `FirstName, LastName, Id, Error` but I need only own Person properties namely : `FirstName, LastName`

How can I get the properties that are only defined on `Person`?

Comment: @Srcee How can I use wrapper class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
var properties = typeof(Person).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                              BindingFlags.Instance |
                                              BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

The `DeclaredOnly` value is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) like this:

> Specifies that only members declared at the level of the supplied type's hierarchy should be considered. Inherited members are not considered.

Comment: @Skeet Thanks. My problem resolved, but one question :
How can I only get properties of string? For example : not include of Assets property in Person class.

Comment: @Ehsan: Use `PropertyInfo.PropertyType` to determine the types. LINQ works well with this sort of thing: `properties.Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string))` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class, for example PersonTemplate which will only have FirstName and LastName properties. Then:

```
public PersonTemplate (Person p)
{
    FirstName = p.FirstName;
    LastName = p.LastName;
}
```